# Angular cli does not use angular 4 by default in ng new

Tags: angular, angular-cli

The following command

```
ng new myprojectname
```

seems to generate angular 1 project, is there a way to set it to angular 4?

Comment: that doesn't make any sense;  Angular cli doesn't have anything to do with Angular 1 (angularjs).  Angular 1 doesn't need to be "generated", it's a drop in .js file.

Comment: Hmm, but I don't see the `component` folder been generated in app, only `controllers` `directives`...etc which are been deprecated in angular 2 and angular 4. Also the console is downloading 1.6.5 when I `ng new myprojectname` . The `bower_components` folder also contains angular 1 files not angular 2 or 4 when I opened them.

Comment: What version of the cli are you using? `ng --version`

Comment: when I print `ng --version` it shows  `--version expects a value`

Comment: it sounds like you are using an older version of angular-cli.  try updating it:  `npm uninstall -g angular-cli` then `npm install --save-dev angular-cli`  https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli

Comment: That is weird. What package did you install for angular cli? Can you try to reinstall it? What does `npm list --depth=0 -g` print?

Comment: @Kim it print `/usr/local/lib
├── @angular/cli@1.2.3
├── angcli@0.0.7
├── bower@1.7.9
├── grunt-cli@1.2.0
├── n@2.1.8
└── npm@2.15.0`  @Claies I see that me try that, the weird part is I just downloaded the latest one before I try `ng new`

Comment: Try `npm uninstall -g angcli`

Comment: you have conflicting packages installed.  `angcli@0.0.7` is http://ngcli.github.io/, which has nothing to do with angular-cli except that they decided to use the same name for the executable (`ng`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the official @angular/cli, you have a different npm package installed which uses the same command `ng`.
You have to do `npm uninstall -g angcli` to get rid of that package to be able to use the official angular cli.

Answer (score 0):

Use ng new myprojectname --ng4

Comment: that is an option, but it wouldn't work in this case, since `ng` was not the official angular-cli to begin with.